# conectar pontos matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graphics

Meu programa plota pontos independentes mas eu gostaria de conectar os `a_min's` e `a_max's`. Como posso fazer isso? No caso, ficariam duas linhas paralelas.

Ele está plotando assim:

'''

```
plt.plot(a_min1, mass1, 'b.')
plt.plot(a_max1, mass1, 'b.')

plt.plot(a_min2, mass2, 'b.')
plt.plot(a_max2, mass2, 'b.')

plt.plot(a_min3, mass3, 'b.')
plt.plot(a_max3, mass3, 'b.')
```

etc

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para plotar uma linha no matplotlib, você deve passar uma lista de coordenadas x e y para o método plt.plot().

Exemplo: `plt.plot([1, 10], [1, 10])` irá traçar uma reta ligando os pontos (1,1) e (10,10) do plano cartesiano.

Segue exemplo funcional, baseado no seu código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dados fictícios    
a_min1 = 1
a_max1 = 5
mass1 = 10

a_min2 = 2
a_max2 = 6
mass2 = 9

a_min3 = 3
a_max3 = 5
mass3 = 8

# Reta 1
plt.plot([a_min1, a_max1], [mass1, mass1])

# Reta 2
plt.plot([a_min2, a_max2], [mass2, mass2])

# Reta 3
plt.plot([a_min3, a_max3], [mass3, mass3])

# Pontos isolados
plt.plot(a_min1, mass1, 'b.')
plt.plot(a_max1, mass1, 'b.')

plt.plot(a_min2, mass2, 'b.')
plt.plot(a_max2, mass2, 'b.')

plt.plot(a_min3, mass3, 'b.')
plt.plot(a_max3, mass3, 'b.')

plt.show()
```

O resultado desse exemplo são retas paralelas, como você previu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]